# Query on Replication Slave fails, but manual execution of query on slave works

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have been in my current replication setup for over a year and suddenly last night at 11:30 PM I started receiving replication 1062 errors that are failing on INSERT ON DUPLICATE queries. The strange thing, though, is when I run the queries manually on the slave, they execute with absolutely no problem.

Even stranger, on a different slave, I am not receiving these errors at all. The queries are running fine.

Here is an example query:

```
                        insert into articles.activity set
                                member_name = "Google",
                                member_id = 0,
                                section = "Article",
                                activity = "Reading <a href=\"https://www.example.com/news/article/\" target=\"_blank\">Example Article</a>.",
                                location = "Articles",
                                ip_address = "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
                                referer = "",
                                a_time = NOW()
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                                member_name = "Google",
                                member_id = 0,
                                section = "Article",
                                activity = "Reading <a href=\"https://www.example.com/news/article/\" target=\"_blank\">Example Article</a>.",
                                location = "Articles",
                                ip_address = "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
                                referer = "",
                                a_time = NOW()
```

This is the table:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| aid         | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| member_name | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| member_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| section     | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| activity    | varchar(300)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address  | varchar(19)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| referer     | varchar(250)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location    | varchar(250)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| a_time      | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Can anyone explain what would suddenly have caused this to happen and why the queries are failing in replication, but work when I manually execute them on the slave?

Comment: What kind of replication do you have, statement or row based? Do you have the same `auto_increment_offset` in all hosts?

Comment: Using mixed (binlog-format=mixed). For auto_increment_offset, all three servers (1 master, 2 x slave) are set to 1.

Comment: The [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) says "an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement against a table having more than one unique or primary key is also marked as unsafe", which is your case, so row based replication is used. This would explain why the query in the slave works, but it doesn't in replication. See [bug #58637](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58637) for more info.

Comment: Any idea why it would suddenly start happening? Furthermore, why replication is operating correctly on my other slave but not this one?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Do you think it's possible that someone (or a script) has written something on the conflicting slave? That could explain it, but I'm just guessing here.